# Returning only specific rows (eg. every 10th: #1, #11, #21...) from query

Tags: solr, solrj

I need to fetch only specific (kind of "nth rows") from a Solr index. For example, if the full result contains 10000 rows, I want to receive only the first and last row of each 100 item bucket.

items 1 and 100
items 101 and 200
items 201 and and 300...

This grouping is dynamic and dependent on the number of results. So, if there are only 5000 total result rows, bucket size is 50 instead of 100. I can calculate the actual indexes but the problem is how to fetch those from Solr.

There are no indexed fields that could be used directly as query parameters. In practise, I am doing a search "name starts with A" (or some other letter) and want to receive 1st item starting with A, 100th item starting with A, 101st item starting with A etc...

Query parameters http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters have "rows" and "start" but these can't skip items, so I would need to get each item with a separate query which is inefficient. I was also thinking about implementing a Filter Query which would just filter out items 2...99, 192...199 but I do not know how to implement that.

Comment: what is the sorting you want?

Comment: First up I'd ask why you have this requirements. It looks like is more about logic than just searching. Can't you just index data in a different way?

Comment: I am creating sort of an index page to alphabetically sorted data. Let's say I would have an index of airports: http://www.world-airport-codes.com/alphabetical/city-name/a.html (I don't actually, but this is an easier example to get).

Now I need to create links to subpages with first and last name of each subpage:

Aachen - Abreojos
Abu Dhabi - Afton
Afutara - Ailinglapalap Island etc.

So when user selects "Aachen - Abreojos" she is displayed all airports between and including those.

So the first Solr query should return a few selected items from the index: Aachen, Abreojos, Abu Dhabi etc.

Comment: And, altering the indexing is not very easy and I would prefer a solution which can work with the existing index structure. I'm going to look into Ansari's suggestion shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way to do this, but this will reduce the amount of data that needs to be passed back and forth: Do a regular query with the usual `start` and `rows` parameters, but tell Solr to only return the ID field of each document (via the [`fl` parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl)). In your client code, store the IDs of the first and last documents, and repeat the query with the next value for `start`. Once you reach the end of the search results, you have a list of the document IDs you want. Run a new query and give it the list of document IDs you want returned, and this time get the full documents.